# How can I analyse all the tracks contained in a folder with Traktor 2 except the tracks of length over X minutes?

Tags: dj, traktor

I want to analyse all the tracks contained in a folder with Traktor 2, including the tracks located in the subfolders.

With Traktor 2.6.5 on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate), I go to to Traktor's preferences and check "Analyze news imported tracks".

[image]

Then in Traktor's browsing window, I go the folder you want to analyze and right-click "Import to Collection". It will analyze all tracks contained in this folder including its subfolders (and recursively):

[image]

Is there anyway to skip the tracks of length over X minutes (X being configurable)? Some tracks are sets so I'd like to skip them:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: So I assume it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traktor 2 currently has no feature to avoid analyzing tracks whose length is over certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

## Very late, I know, but for anyone else looking for an answer you can by:

1. Activate the "Time" column if you haven't already by right-clicking a column header in the explorer and activating "Time" in the drop-down.
2. Sort your folder/album by Time (Ascending) by left-clicking the "Time" column header.
3. Click on the first song you want imported.
4. Scroll down to the last song you want imported (Longest song you want imported) and SHIFT + click.
5. Right-click and Import to collection > as Tracks
6. After all songs have been analyzed, disable the auto-analyze on import and import all of the larger songs to the collection.

This would all be a lot easier if there were a way to disable analysis of larger songs, but here you go.